# ListView.builder not displaying anything

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In the Scaffold in the build method, I tried replacing the body with

1. a Container with a specified height, wrapped around _questionList()  (which returns a ListView.builder),
2. a Column that has one child, Expanded, which wraps around _questionList()

None of them works. The first two clauses in the if-else block inside the builder function is passed. What could the error possibly be?

```
class _QuestionPageState extends State<QuestionPage> {
  final String roomName;
  final String roomID;

  _QuestionPageState(this.roomName, this.roomID);

  Widget _questionList() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: RoomDbService(roomName, roomID).getRoomQuestions(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) { // passed
            return new Text('Loading...');
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) { // passed
          return new Text("Error...");
        } else {
          // snapshot.data.documents.forEach((element) {print(element);}); (prints nothing)

          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final docSS = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                // print(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["text"]);  (prints nothing)

                //return Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["text"]);  (returns nothing)

                return QuestionTile(
                  questionID: docSS.documentID,
                  text: docSS.data["text"],
                  roomName: roomName,
                  roomID: roomID
                );
           }
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    RoomDbService dbService = RoomDbService(roomName, roomID);

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: ... ,

      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 500,
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([_questionList()]),
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Surely there's no problem with the stream if I managed to enter the 3rd clause of the if-else block right?

Comment: Try `print(snapshot.data.documents.length)` before `return ListView.builder(` and see the length in the console. The list could just be empty.

Comment: @MickaelHrndz Hi, thanks, i found out that the list is empty and that the issue lied somewhere deep in my code

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this code

```
class _QuestionPageState extends State<QuestionPage> {
  final String roomName;
  final String roomID;

  _QuestionPageState(this.roomName, this.roomID);

  Widget _questionList() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: RoomDbService(roomName, roomID).getRoomQuestions(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) { // passed
            return new Text('Loading...');
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) { // passed
          return new Text("Error...");
        } else {
          // snapshot.data.documents.forEach((element) {print(element);}); (prints nothing)

          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

              if (itemCount === 0) return Text('item count value is 0');
                final docSS = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                // print(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["text"]);  (prints nothing)

                //return Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["text"]);  (returns nothing)

                return QuestionTile(
                  questionID: docSS.documentID,
                  text: docSS.data["text"],
                  roomName: roomName,
                  roomID: roomID
                );
           }
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    RoomDbService dbService = RoomDbService(roomName, roomID);

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: ... ,

      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 500,
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([_questionList()]),
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below solution :

```
return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              shrinkWrap : true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

              if (itemCount === 0) return Text('item count value is 0');
                final docSS = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                // print(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["text"]);  (prints nothing)

                //return Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["text"]);  (returns nothing)

                return QuestionTile(
                  questionID: docSS.documentID,
                  text: docSS.data["text"],
                  roomName: roomName,
                  roomID: roomID
                );
           }
          );
```

You can use shrinWrap : true

`